# #Error in rdlc report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a stored procedure that return data set to the rdlc. The particular field that I'm looking for when executed in SQL does not return any null or empty values. But however when the report is rendered, the value returned is #error.

My expression is `=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MinScoreValue.Value),0,Fields!MinScoreValue.Value)`

MinScoreValue is a function returned value. The datatype of the return value of function is int. The Data Type in the data table(xsd) for the corresponding field is System.Int32

Comment: What do you get if you just use `=Fields!MinScoreValue.Value` for your expression?

Comment: If I don't use any conditions, I get a blank. (nothing)

Comment: The error maybe caused by formatting expression as well. Do you have any special formatting applied to the field?

Comment: I don't have any formatting for this particular cell/field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake of using one data set for the report and changing it to another data set with the MinScoreValue field later but never updated my code behind to use the new stored procedure.